# DetourPro Redirect Home Page

Tags: redirects, detour-pro

I have a client that was purchased by another company, and they've asked to have several pages redirect to analogous destinations on the new parent company's site, but they want to maintain access to their current Control Panel.

I'm using DetourPro to manage most of the redirects, but can't figure out how to get it to redirect the home page.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't! See this [support post](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/detour-pro/viewthread/8421).

Just tried it and entered "/" for the string to match and it does work, but then locks you out of the Control Panel, as the /admin.php gets re-written also. :( You might not be affected by the control panel logout if your control panel access isn't in the root.

Otherwise you'll have to do it in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /  http://parentcompany.com/wherever/you/want/to/go
```

Alternatively you could add a [template tag redirect](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#redirect) on the homepage that goes to a different URL that then catches in Detour Pro (bit of poor approach though as bad for SEO to have multiple redirects).

Comment: I thought about the template tag, but yes, it's poor SEO. Thanks for trying.